# If x number of posts repeat code for second set of posts WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, carousel

I am working on a carousel to display posts from wordpress. After 4 posts it should add a new row and item and all the code contained between them.

Here is the code I have so far, not sure what the best way to do it is without repeating too much code.

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <!--<div id="recent-post-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#recent-post-carousel" data-slide-to="0" <div class=" <?php if( $the_query->current_post == 0 ):?>active<?php endif; ?>"></li>
                    <li data-target="#recent-post-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#recent-post-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>-->




                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="single-post">
                                    <div class="pull-left post-image">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <?php  echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
                                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-right post-details">
                                        <p class="post-date"> <?php the_date(); ?></p>
                                        <a href="#"><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5></a>
                                        <span> <?php the_author(); ?> </span>
                                         <p> <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,90).' [...]'; ?> </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/.item--> 
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: so you want to repeat at `<div class="row">` after every 4 results?

Comment: Repeat the Row div and all the child elements in it. basically every 4 posts should be a new row.